# Kinetic.js: Why does the image show only on the second call to the function?

Tags: kineticjs

and then both images are shown

function addImage(src){

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = src;

    var imagenew = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 80,
      y: 80,
      image: imageObj,
      width: 65, 
      height: 65,
  name:'imagename',
  draggable:true
  }); // end new image

layer.add(imagenew);
layer.draw();
```

} // end addImage

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give the imageObj time to load by using an onload callback:

```
var imagenew;

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload=function(){
    imagenew = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 80,
        y: 80,
        image: imageObj,
        width: 65, 
        height: 65,
        name:'imagename',
        draggable:true
    }); // end new image
    layer.add(imagenew);
    layer.draw();
}
imageObj.src = src;
```